# Proving that $a_m a_{m+1}$ is a part of a sequence

Tags: sequences-and-series, proof-writing

Deﬁne the sequence $a_1, a_2, a_3, . . .$ by $a_1 = 4, a_2 = 7$ and for $n ≥ 2$,
$a_{n+1} = 2a_n − a_{n−1} + 2$.
Prove that, for every positive integer m, the number $a_m a_{m+1}$ is a term of the sequence.

I'm really struggling with question above. I have so far found that $a_n=n^2+3$ and have found that for $a_m a_{m+1}$,  $n=m^2+m+3$ and that $a_n$ is part of the sequence. For example, $a_1a_2=4 \times 7=28$, $n=1^2+1+3=5$ and if you check the sequence, the 5th term is 28 so 28 is part of the sequence. I have tried a proof by induction but this has not worked for me and I am a bit lost.

Comment: You seem done to me. What are you struggling with? EG Are you trying to prove that $a_n = n^2+3$, and have only "observed" the pattern so far?

Answer (score 2):

You have almost solved it. Let me give a formal proofs.

\begin{align}
a_n - a_{n-1} &= a_{n-1} - a_{n-2} + 2\\
a_{n-1} - a_{n-2} &= a_{n-2} - a_{n-3} + 2\\
&\; \vdots\\
a_3 - a_2 &= a_2 - a_1 + 2
\end{align}

Adding all up, we get
\begin{align} 
&a_{n} - a_2 = a_{n-1} - a_1 + 2(n-2)\\
\implies &a_n - a_{n-1} = 7 - 4 + 2(n-2) = 2n -1
\end{align}

Then again using addition, we will get
$$a_n - a_1 = 2(n+\cdots+2) -(n-1) = n(n+1) - 2-n+1 = (n+1)(n-1) = n^2 - 1$$

So, $a_n = n^2 + 3$.

Then, for next part
\begin{align}
a_m a_{m+1} &= (m^2 + 3) [(m+1)^2 + 3]\\
&=(m^2 + 3)(m^2 + 2m + 4)\\
&= m^4 + 2m^3 +7m^2+6m + 12\\
&= m^4 + m^2 + 9 + 2m^3 + 6m^2 + 6m + 3\\
&= (m^2 + m + 3)^2 + 3
\end{align}

Comment: Side note: To somewhat demystify the expansion at the end $$(m^2 + 3) [ (m+1)^2 + 3] = [(m + \sqrt{3}i) ( m - \sqrt{3}i) ] [ (m+1+\sqrt{3}i) ( m+1 - \sqrt{3} i )] =  [ (m+\sqrt{3} I )( m+1 - \sqrt{3} i ) ] [ ( m - \sqrt{3}i)(m+1+\sqrt{3}i) ] = [ m^2 + m + 3 + \sqrt{3} I ] [ m^2 + m + 3 - \sqrt{3} i ] = (m^2 + m + 3) ^2 + 3.$$ Admittedly this is much more complicated than the simple expansion, but provides the motivation for why $n = m^2 + m + 3$ would work. We can also make some generalizations from there.

Comment: Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

Since you found $a_n=n^2+3$, I will start from here.
\begin{align*}
a_m a_{m+1} &= (m^2 + 3)\left[ (m+1)^2 + 3 \right]\\
&= [m(m+1)]^2 + 3[m^2+(m+1)^2] + 9 \\
&= (m^2 + m)^2 + 3(2m^2 + 2m + 1) + 9 \\
&= (m^2 + m + 3)^2 + 3
\end{align*}
Hence we showed $a_m a_{m+1}$ appeared at ($m^2 + m + 3$)th term of the sequence.